# How to set the initial ListView item background color with a selector

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I cannot wrap my head around this, I want to set the initial background color of my list view items to grey, but they only take the right background color after I have selected them (and deselected) the first time. Which attributes are not configured properly in the first `item` definition?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/grey" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/>
</selector>
```

Also tried to set the background of the list view item directly, but then the selector does not have any effect anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For list items define a selector drawable:

**res/drawable/list_item_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red" /> <!-- Pressed state -->
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- Focused state -->
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/orange" /> <!-- Selected state -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" /> <!-- Default state -->    

</selector>
```

- Set the above drawable as background for individual list item:

**res/layout/list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_background" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listitem" />

</LinearLayout>
```

- Use the above custom layout for creating the list items:

  `String[] mStrings = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
  ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
  list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.listitem ,mStrings));`

Comment: Using the attribute `android:background` on the **`item.xml`** rather than the attribute `android:listSelector` on the **`ListView`** element solved it, for whatever reasons..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying with the following definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

State List Drawables try matching in order. If you want a "default" drawable for many cases, it should be the last one, with no state flags. From [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList):

> During each state change, the state list is traversed top to bottom
>   and the first item that matches the current state is used—the
>   selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first item
>   that meets the minimum criteria of the state.

Comment: Indeed, haven't tried to change the order with that one yet, unfortunately it does not work either... on the Android layout viewer it even has the right color

Comment: @Mahoni How/where are you setting this background?

Comment: @matiash Directly in the layout where I use the `ListView` element with the attribute `android:listSelector="@drawable/my_listview_selector"`

Answer (score 1):

Also tried to set the background of the list view item directly, **but then the selector does not have any effect anymore**.

If I am not mistaken, selector is drawn behind the list item(by default). Since you set solid grey color to your list item, the red color from the selector doesn't show. You can confirm this by changing the way you have defined `@color/grey` - try adding a low alpha value to it. In this case the red color should come through.

You can of course change this behavior by setting `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` - default is false. The list item will however be hidden when the selector is drawn on top.

Anyway - from what you have said, you want the items to have `@color/red` background when pressed and `@color/grey` background otherwise.

See if the following satisfies your requirements:

Selector drawable for **list item views**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:drawable="color/grey" />
</selector>
```

For the `listSelector` attribute, only provide the color value:

```
<ListView
    ....
    ....
    android:listSelector="@color/red" >
</ListView>
```

In a few words, the item background color is `transparent` when the list item is pressed - allowing the listSelector `red color` to be visible. In all other cases, the `grey` color is visible.

Comment: That looks the most promising. The list view's `android:listSelector` is set to `@color/red`, but where do I set the defined `<selector>` then? On the `item.xml` and if yes, on which attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a listselector.xml under your drawable folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
     android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
     android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

Then inside your listview add :

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector should be similar to the one below:

List_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
     android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
     android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

Then in the drawables folder, you need to create the following 2 files:

gradient_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

  <gradient
      android:startColor="#cfcfcf"
      android:centerColor="#737374"
      android:endColor="##3e3e3e"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

gradient_bg_hover.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#7f0000"
      android:centerColor="#660000"
      android:endColor="#4c0000"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Finally, in the listview, you need to add the following line of code:

```
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No, sorry using gradients changes nothing.

Comment: as everyone is telling you, you need to set 3 states in the list_selector.xml file:

<item android:state_selected = "false" />
<item android:state_pressed = "true" />
<item android:state_selected = "true" />

Comment: Yes, I tried that ;-) Using `background` on the `item.xml` solves it not the three state approach.